# The '--lang=en_US' Chromium switcher contains unsupported language value

Tags: java, chromium, jxbrowser

I am using JxBrowser 6.14, and I get this error when starting a jxbrowser instance:

```
com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.ipc.IPCException: Failed to start IPC process.
    at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.ipc.d.run(SourceFile:190)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The '--lang=en_US' Chromium switcher contains unsupported language value. Use one of the following language values: am, ar, bg, bn, ca, cs, da, de, el, en, en_gb, es, es_419, et, fa, fi, fil, fr, gu, he, hi, hr, hu, id, it, ja, kn, ko, lt, lv, ml, mr, ms, nb, nl, pl, pt_br, pt_pt, ro, ru, sk, sl, sr, sv, sw, ta, te, th, tr, uk, vi, zh_cn, zh_tw.
    at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.ipc.ChromiumProcess.a(SourceFile:178)
    at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.ipc.ChromiumProcess.start(SourceFile:103)
    at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.ipc.d.run(SourceFile:184)
    ... 1 more
```

I didn't have that problem yesterday. I don't know what changed.

Comment: Try `--lang=en`? As for why it changed, did your Chromium update automatically?

Comment: @simonwo thanks for the swift reply ! The thing is, I don't think I am ever setting this variable anywhere. I can't see jxbrowser.chromium.internal package source code, so I don't know where it comes from

Comment: Could you please provide us with more details on the issue. What JxBrowser version do you use? Do you run on macOS, Windows, Linux? What has changed since yesterday? Maybe you use Maven to get JxBrowser JARs and the version of JxBrowser has been updated?

Comment: Version 6.14 on Mac. Since my post I learned that a commit was pushed, which passed "--lang=en_US" as argument, whereas before we weren't passing anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the issue wasn't reproducible with an old JxBrowser version. Once you upgraded to 6.14, you started seeing this error message. The reason is that in one of the latest JxBrowser versions, language check functionality has been updated. Now it validates the `--lang=en_US` parameter and checks whether Chromium has appropriate language resource (`*.pak`).

The error message indicates that the `en_US.pak` file doesn't exist in Chromium, so you have to use one of the suggested languages. To solve the issue use the `--lang=en` switcher.

Comment: @Vladimir I think it's a bit harsh to make the whole thing crash just because of this. This should be a warning. Or at list put it as a huge red thing in your release notes. This caused us some issues.

Comment: @qwertzguy the exception message indicates that the passed input parameter for the --lang switcher is incorrect. We cannot just ignore this error and just show some warning in the log that is disabled by default. The ignored errors cause unexpected behavior in the application and logical bugs.

Comment: @Vladimir the thing is, it was completely ignored before and now it throws an unchecked exception. There should have been at least a transition phase where it logs (as error if you prefer, we enable warning logs by default) before doing something that kills a thread. When you make a library you should not assume how it is used and should lean on the safe side of things.